# Writing a really good ASP.Net Async HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

Until recently I thought that I wrote some really smart IHttpAsyncHandler. The functionality of the handler boils down to bypassing cross domain restrictions to a predefined host for a full Ajax webapp. So the incoming request is validated and then immediately dispatched to the real server using an ordinary HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse.

Today during debugging I discovered that Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread returns true on the BeginGetResponse callback. Which means I've exchanged one ThreadPool Thread for another. Great :)

Anyone who could suggest an alternative implementation?